# Is "non durable" subscription not supported by the C#/net Azure Servicebus SDK? (How to delete orphaned subscriptions)

Tags: c#, .net, azureservicebus, publish-subscribe, servicebus

Currently working on a microservice architecture where we are using scale out(multiple instances) on Azure AppServices.

Is this scenario i want to "broadcast" a message to all running instances with updates to their running configuration.

Each instance subscribes to a topic to get the messages containing updates to the running configuration.

So far, so good.

The problem arises when instances are shut down and new ones are created. This leaves orphaned subscriptions that builds up messages.

It seems that non durable subscriptions is what I need. But the Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus nuget package that I'm using does not seem to support this?

Answer (score 0):

> How to delete orphaned subscriptions

Here the **Queues/Subscriptions** would be created and removed based on use as opposed to the current explicit provisioning model for these entities.

**Service Bus** provides you with the APIs to perform create/delete operations so you can plug these on role ***OnStart/OnStop*** events appropriately. If those operations fail for some reason then the orphaned entities will exist. Again you can run clean up operation on them based on some unique identifier for the name of the entities. An example of this can be seen here:  http://windowsazurecat.com/2011/08/how-to-simplify-scale-inter-role-communication-using-windows-azure-service-bus/

Externally, orphan detection can be implemented in a variety of ways. For example, whenever a message is sent or received, update a timestamp in a SQL database to indicate that the `Queue/Topic/Subscription` is still active. This `timestamp` is then used to identify orphans.

To clean out subscriptions, you can probably use the `AccessedAt` property of the `SubscriptionDescription` and use that to check when someone last read the queue (by a Receive operation).

**Reference:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptiondescription.accessedat.aspx